# BST problems in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
class BST:
    """A Binary Search Tree."""

    def __init__(self: 'BST', container: list =None) -> None:
        """
        Initialize this BST by inserting the items from container (default [])
        one by one, in the order given.
        """
        # Initialize empty tree.
        self.root = None
        # Insert every item from container.
        if container:
            for item in container:
                self.insert(item)

   def insert(self: 'BST', item: object) -> None:
    """
    Insert item into this BST.
    """
    # Find the point of insertion.
    parent, current = None, self.root
    while current:
        if item < current.item:
            parent, current = current, current.left
        else:  # item > current.item
            parent, current = current, current.right
    # Create a new node and link it in appropriately.
    new_node = _BSTNode(item)
    if parent:
        if item < parent.item:
            parent.left = new_node
        else:  # item > parent.item
            parent.right = new_node
    else:
        self.root = new_node
```

this is the code that I built for the BST class, I would like implement a **max_node** function that finds the maximum node **without using recursion** , how am I suppose to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this without using recursion? How big is this tree?

Answer (score 0):

In a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), the maximum node is simply the right-most node, so start at the head and just keep taking right children until you hit a node with no right child. This can easily be done iteratively (and in fact, that's probably how I would do it anyway).

In pseudocode:

```
max_node = head

while hasRightChild(max_node)
    max_node = max_node.right_child;
```